# Super easy tutorial throwing django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet

Tags: django, django-models

I created a simple django web app. When I run the models.py file I get the following error. I've tried a number of solutions including taking out my apps one by one, reinstalling django (I have version 2.0) doing an 'ol system restart, inserting import django + django.setup(), refreshing the virtualenv.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/Pritee/djangogirls/blog/models.py", line 6, in <module>
class Post(models.Model):
File "C:\Users\Pritee\djangogirls\myvenv\lib\site-
packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 100, in __new__
app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
File "C:\Users\Pritee\djangogirls\myvenv\lib\site-
packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 244, in get_containing_app_config
self.check_apps_ready()
File "C:\Users\Pritee\djangogirls\myvenv\lib\site-
packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 127, in check_apps_ready
raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

Models.py

```
from django.db import models

from django.utils import timezone


class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(
            default=timezone.now)
published_date = models.DateTimeField(
        blank=True, null=True)

def publish(self):
    self.published_date = timezone.now()
    self.save()

def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

Settings.py

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'iua)_567ww!*c9#dhg#f&u4ft$(47!cz@98!$ro=^+u!+t'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'blog'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
    'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-
validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
{
    'NAME': 
'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
},
{
    'NAME': 
'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
},
{
    'NAME': 
'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
},
{
    'NAME': 
'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
},
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

---

[command prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e377e.png) error trace picture

---

My repo is [here](http://github.com/PriteeTem/events):  (It has slightly different naming since I tried doing the tutorial again from scratch to see if I could fix it)

---

Comment: Can you show which command you are running at the terminal and from which path?

Comment: What do you mean by "run models.py file"?

Comment: @oxalorg - In pycharm, I execute the models.py file within my "blog" application.

Comment: @ThierryLam I'm running my code in pycharm but have also tried running it from the terminal within a virtual environment

Comment: From the command, line you should start the server from `C:/Users/Pritee/djangogirls/` with `python manage.py runserver` to run the dev server of your site. In your browser, it will be accessible at `localhost:8000` by default

Comment: @ThierryLam From command I active my virtual environment (within the djangogirls folder) and am able to `python manage.py runserver` then I can visit http://127.0.0.1:8000/ and it shows that django is installed/success message. The trouble is my templates/views don't work because model.py is throwing this error. In my template/html I use {{posts}} and the {{ do not cue django, they are read as html.

Comment: Which url are you accessing for you to get that error message?

Comment: @ThierryLam I added a picture of my command line that is giving me that error when I execute models.py. Hopefully that answers the question, really appreciate the help

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by running `python models.py`? It is not a valid execution of the model file.

Comment: @ThierryLam. Ahh, didn't know that. Shouldn't models.py be executable without error? I'm having trouble getting my html to load in the models and figured it was because models.py was throwing errors so went back to the source.

Answer (score 0):

I think you got an indentation error at line 6 of class post. Just use a tab before published date.

Try this in your models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Comment: @apron - thank you, I made the update but didn't seem to have an impact (still throwing the error). Its crapping out in the line "class Post(models.Model):"

Comment: from your models.py It seemed the problem.
But If it does not solve the problem then you can share your project @github and share the link here so that someone can inspect your project. 
:)

Comment: My repo is here: https://github.com/PriteeTem/events (It has slightly different naming since I tried doing the tutorial again from scratch to see if I could fix it)